# How to sort dictionary in python based on several parameter?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have four individual dictionary with same keys as follow:

```
s = {'name': 'Spain', 'wins': 1, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal, difference': 4, 'points': 4}
e = {'name': 'England', 'wins': 2, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6}
p = {'name': 'Portugal', 'wins': 0, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 2, 'goal difference': 0, 'points': 2}
g = {'name': 'Germany', 'wins': 1, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 5, 'points': 4}
```

The goal is to sort them based on 'points' and if it is equal, it have to be sorted based on alphabet name as follow:

```
'England' 'wins': 2 'loses' : 1 'draws': 0 'goal difference': 1 'points': 6
'Germany' 'wins': 1 'loses' : 1 'draws': 1 'goal difference': 5 'points': 4
'Spain' 'wins': 1 'loses' : 1 'draws': 1 'goal, difference': 4 'points': 4
'Portugal' 'wins': 0 'loses' : 1 'draws': 2 'goal difference': 0 'points': 2
```

Any idea would be great.

Comment: Make a list of all dict like list of dict and then apply `newlist = sorted(listofdict, key=lambda k: (k['points'], k['name']))`   `listofdict = [s,e,p,g]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = {'name': 'Spain', 'wins': 1, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal, difference': 4, 'points': 4}
e = {'name': 'England', 'wins': 2, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': 1, 'points': 6}
p = {'name': 'Portugal', 'wins': 0, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 2, 'goal difference': 0, 'points': 2}
g = {'name': 'Germany', 'wins': 1, 'loses' : 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 5, 'points': 4}

l = [s, e, p, g]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x['points'], x['name']))
```

Comment: it works thanks, just I need to find a way to print it in correct order like above, as you know keys are shown out o order in dictionary.

Comment: just another question can I add more parameters for sorting? How would it be if I want to sort it based on 'points', 'goal difference' and then alphabet name?

Comment: @Babak Before Python 3.6, a dict is an unordered collection. So if you need to print the items in a specific order you should create a list containing the key strings in the desired order.

Comment: @BabakMemar Should the goal difference be sorted ascending or descending?

Comment: @PM2Ring for the points it should be sorted descending and ascending for alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a `key` parameter to the Python stdlib `sort` or `sorted` function to customize sorting. In your case it would be:

```
custom_order = sorted([s, e, p, g], key=lambda d: (-d['points'], d['name']))
```

Explanation: the sorting in our case compares dynamically created tuples of negative points count and name. The tuples are compared by first elements, and if these are equal, by second etc. So your dicts will be compared by points, and if points are equal, by name, as you wanted. The points are negative to achieve descending order on points, but keep an ascending one on names.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to have your own function instead lambda function, it would be:

```
def sort_func(x):
    return -x['points'], x['name']

for d in sorted([s ,e, p, g], key=sort_func):
    print(d)
```